# Given $n$, find $a,b$ such that $a^b = n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given $n$, find $a,b$ such that $a^b=n$.

All three variables involved are positive integers. Assume that $n > b > 1$. Not all n will have a solution of course, but some will.
How does one go about this?

Comment: It is a good practice to have the question as part the post itself (not just in the title).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can factorise $n$ easily, then write $n$ down as its prime factorisation and it will be clear what $a,b$ can be.

Comment: Excellent! So a and b only exist when the prime factorization results in a single number?

Comment: @Typhon Think about an example, let's take $n=36$ which we know has solution $a=6, b=2$. Then $36 = 2^2 3^2$. What do you notice about its prime factorisation? Now also consider $n=216=6^3 = 2^3 3^3$. What if we have $n=2^3 3^2 = 72$? Why does this have no solution?

Comment: Ah...this is really nice. Reduce to terms of a single degree, and combine the bases, keeping the degree. Thank you!

Comment: @Typhon Yep! Just don't forget that when the common degree has divisors, there are more solutions. E.g. Let $n = 2^63^6$. Then we can write $n = 6^6$ but also $n=(6^2)^3 = (6^3)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

You factor $n$ into prime factorization.
The brute force way is to pick all primes between $3$ and $\sqrt{n}$ and divide them brute force until it factors.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Pick a prime in this range and then divide it until it factors? It's prime.

Might a more elegant solution involve playing with antilogs and different bases?

Comment: @Typhon no, pick $3$ and divide $n$ by $3$. If it does not divide, pick $5$ and try again... (assuming $n$ is odd, otherwise trivially take out a power of $2$).

Comment: @Typhon alternatively you can use the sieve of eratosthenes